# How to fix buffer-local variable?

Tags: init-file, line-numbers

I have the following in my init.el,

```
(setq-default display-line-numbers 'visual)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
```

which should give me relative line numbering. On starting emacs, it does on the startup page, but as soon as I switch to another file, the `display-line-numbers` variable is overriden to `t`, which removes relative line numbering. I am confused, as I thought that setting `setq-default` would ensure that new buffers would default to `visual`. Or is there something else going on that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do `C-h f display-line-numbers-mode` I see this as part of the doc:

> **To change the type of line numbers displayed by default,
> customize `display-line-numbers-type`.**  To change the type while
> the mode is on, set `display-line-numbers` directly.

Have you tried doing that?  Dunno whether that will help.  If it does, then maybe the doc string of `global-display-line-numbers-mode` should also say something about this.

---

(I filed doc bug #[48511](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=48511) for this.)

Comment: i should really read the docs...... kept thinking it was something overriding the variable (but yes it worked!)